# Improve the performance of an AutoComplete LINQ Query

Tags: c#, ajax, linq

I have some massive searches happening for my AutoComplete and was wondering if someone could give any ideas to improve the performance.

What happens:

1) At application launch I am saving all database entries on the memory.

2) User types in the search box to initiate AutoComplete:

```
$("#MatterCode").width(110).kendoAutoComplete({
        minLength: 3,
        delay: 10,
        dataTextField: "MatterCode",
        template: '<div class="autoCompleteResultsCode"> ${ data.ClientCode } - ${ data.MatterCode } - ${ data.ClientName } - ${ data.MatterName }</div>',
        dataSource: {
            serverFiltering: true,
            transport: {
                read: "/api/matter/AutoCompleteByCode",
                parameterMap: function() {
                    var matterCode = $("#MatterCode").val();
                    return { searchText: matterCode };
                }
            }
        }, //More Stuff here
```

3) It goes to my controller class:

```
public JsonResult AutoCompleteByCode(string searchText)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchText))
    {
        Response.StatusCode = 500;
        return Json(new
        {
            Error = "search string can't be empty"
        });
    }

    var results = _publishedData.GetMattersForAutoCompleteByCode(searchText).Select(
            matter => new
            {
                MatterCode = matter.Code,
                MatterName = matter.Name,
                ClientCode = matter.Client.Code,
                ClientName = matter.Client.Name
            });
    return Json(results);
}
```

4) Which goes into the DAL (objects starting with '_' are Memory Objects)

```
public virtual IEnumerable<Matter> GetMattersForAutoCompleteByCode(string input)
{
    InvalidateCache();
    IEnumerable<Matter> results;
    //Searching Matter Object on all 4 given parameters by input.

    if (_lastMatters != null && input.StartsWith(_lastSearch) && _lastMatters.Any())
    {
        results = _lastMatters.Where(m => m.IsInputLike(input)).OrderBy(m => m.Code);
        _lastMatters = results;
    }
    else
    {
        results = _matters.Where(m => m.IsInputLike(input)).OrderBy(m => m.Code);
        _lastMatters = results;
    }

    _lastSearch = input;

    return results.Take(10).ToList();
}
```

5) isInputLike is an internal bool method

```
internal bool IsInputLike(string input)
{
    //Check to see if the input statement exists in any of the 4 fields
    bool check = (Code.ToLower().Contains(input.Trim().ToLower()) 
            || Name.ToLower().Contains(input.Trim().ToLower()) 
            || ClientCode.ToLower().Contains(input.Trim().ToLower()) 
            || ClientName.ToLower().Contains(input.Trim().ToLower()));

    return check;
}
```

Now the result set that I have to work with can range over 100,000. Now the first Autocomplete of any new query has to search through 400,000 records and I can't think of a way to improve the performance without sacrificing the feature.

Any ideas? 
Is SQL stored proc calls faster than LINQ?

Comment: You have posted this question in a wrong forum. Check http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Thanks Somya, I will keep it in mind in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well  i recommend you to create a view that contains all of the names e.g. (code, name, Clientcode, ClientName) into a single column concatenated say FullName and replace your IsInputLike(..) as below:

```
internal bool IsInputLike(string input)
{
    //Check to see if the input statement exists in any of the 4 fields
    return FullName.Contains(input);

}
```

Comment: I just made the change and it improved the performance quite a bit. Thanks! 

Makes total sense too, instead of checking 4 strings one after another. I am just checking one string now.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not much of an asp/http guy but when I see this:

```
internal bool IsInputLike(string input)
{
    //Check to see if the input statement exists in any of the 4 fields
    bool check = (Code.ToLower().Contains(input.Trim().ToLower()) 
        || Name.ToLower().Contains(input.Trim().ToLower()) 
        || ClientCode.ToLower().Contains(input.Trim().ToLower()) 
        || ClientName.ToLower().Contains(input.Trim().ToLower()));

    return check;
}
```

I think you are creating a lot of new string; and that has to take some time.  Try this and see if this improves your performance

```
var inp = input.Trim();
bool chk = (Code.IndexOf(inp, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) > -1)
                || (Name.IndexOf(inp, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) > -1)
                || (ClientCode.IndexOf(inp, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) > -1)
                || (ClientName.IndexOf(inp, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) > -1);
```

This first line (that creates inp) isn't that important since the compiler should optimize repeated usage, but I think it reads better.

The IndexOf method will not create new strings and with the StringComparison parameter you can avoid creating all the ToLower strings.

Comment: Indeed, I was going to post the same thing - doing ToLower().Trim().ToLower() etc... well always cause another instance of a string to be built internally at runtime thus causing more mem consumption AND extra hits. Also the suggestion about using small sets of data to work with will definitely help and is the recommended way of doing so. Alternatively, you need to setup a cache to store ALL objects and have a dependency on SQL Server so data gets updated at intervals or the like. One less hit to the DB all the time but still an overkill for what you wanna do!

Comment: Thanks both you guys, I have implemented it and it did improve the performance.

And for requirements reasons I do not have the option to limit the data.

I am going to try and see how the SQL query performs. Primarily the db with the data is just a viewing DB and we do not create any Stored Procs on it (Don't ask me why lol). So, I have to mirror the View on another DB and test it out there.

Thanks for the responses :)

Answer (score 2):

I think the main issue here is you placing the 400k objects in memory to start with.
SQL is not all that slow, it's better to start with a limited set of data in the first place.

one obvious optimisation is:

```
internal bool IsInputLike(string input)
{
    string input = input.Trim().ToLower();
    //Check to see if the input statement exists in any of the 4 fields
    bool check = (Code.ToLower().Contains(input) 
            || Name.ToLower().Contains(input) 
            || ClientCode.ToLower().Contains(input) 
            || ClientName.ToLower().Contains(input));

    return check;
}
```

but personally, I would keep the data where it belongs, in the SQL server (if that's what you are using).
Some indexing and the proper queries could make this faster.

When I see this code I start wondering:

```
public virtual IEnumerable<Matter> GetMattersForAutoCompleteByCode(string input)
{
    InvalidateCache();
    IEnumerable<Matter> results;
    //Searching Matter Object on all 4 given parameters by input.

    if (_lastMatters != null && input.StartsWith(_lastSearch) && _lastMatters.Any())
    {
        results = _lastMatters.Where(m => m.IsInputLike(input)).OrderBy(m => m.Code);
        _lastMatters = results;
    }
    else
    {
        results = _matters.Where(m => m.IsInputLike(input)).OrderBy(m => m.Code);
        _lastMatters = results;
    }

    _lastSearch = input;

    return results.Take(10).ToList();
}
```

why do you need to order? Why does a dropdown autocomplete need to filter on 4 items? if you only take 10 anyway can't you just not order? See if removing the orderby gives you any better results, especially in the else statement where you'll have many results.

personally i'd go all in for LINQ to SQL and let the SQL server do the searching. optimize the indexing on this table and it'll be much faster.

Comment: The reason I am reordering is because the list generated does not have matters organized by their matter numbers (and it is a requirement). But your comment made me think why don't I do it while I am generating the list in the memory and save real time processing power. 

I will look into calling it from SQL and see how it performs :)

Thanks!